Can I use a lambda expression to return a single value of a collections?
I have a Collection of  and I want to make a simple filter to obtain a T value, for example an
getById( int idOfT)

I tried this:
return (T) stream.filter( t -> t.getId().equals(id));

but it does't work and show me this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2 cannot be cast to class T


after the filter, which returns a Stream, you must add some operation like findFirst() or FindAny(), which returns an Optional, more calls needed like orElse() or orElseThrow()

(obviously I meant findAny() and not FindAny()...)

Missing terminal operation on stream
A stream has three parts:

A source such as a collection of objects.
Intermediate operations.
Terminal operation.

You are missing the third, a terminal operation. You defined a filter but never did anything with the result. And, streams are lazy in that no processing happens until you apply a terminal operation.
Here is an example where we apply a terminal operation after filtering.
Define a record as our custom class, Pet. By the way, notice that a record can be defined locally — very handy for building reports, etc.
record Pet( String species , String name ) { }

Some sample data.
List < Pet > pets =
        List.of(
                new Pet( "Dog" , "Boo" ) ,
                new Pet( "Cat" , "Fluffy" ) ,
                new Pet( "Cat" , "Spot" ) ,
                new Pet( "Bird" , "Bucky" )
        );

Example code with filter and terminal operation
Now the main event: Create a stream, filter for our desired element, and stop when any one is found. We perform that stop with a call to Stream#findAny.
A minor note: We use findAny rather than findFirst to give the stream implementation the flexibility of filtering any part of the stream in any order. We do not care about the first pet named Spot, we want any pet named Spot. You should choose the terminal operation that fits your needs and logic.
Optional < Pet > optionalPetNamedSpot =
        pets
                .stream( )
                .filter( ( Pet pet ) -> pet.name.equalsIgnoreCase( "Spot" ) )
                .findAny( );

We get back an Optional. An Optional is a wrapper that either carries an object of our desired type (a Pet here), or carries nothing (if no pet at all were named Spot). Using Optional avoids the tragedy of null.
Dump to console.
System.out.println( "optionalPetNamedSpot = " + optionalPetNamedSpot );

When run:
optionalPetNamedSpot = Optional[Pet[species=Cat, name=Spot]]

If you need the actual Pet object, test that the Optional has one (is not empty), and then call one of the methods like Optional#get.
if( optionalPetNamedSpot.isPresent() )
{
    Pet petNamedSpot = optionalPetNamedSpot.get() ;
    …
} 
else
{
    … handle situation where no Pet was found to have a name of "Spot". 
}

If we wanted all pets named Spot rather than any one pet named Spot, we would use a different terminal operation. We would use something like toList to produce a List of matching objects.
List < Pet > petsNamedSpot =
        pets
                .stream()
                .filter( ( Pet pet ) -> pet.name.equalsIgnoreCase( "Spot" ) )
                .toList();

Map
If you are frequently retrieving an object from your collection, filtering may not be the most efficient approach.
A Map is a collection of key-value pairs, where if you know the key, you can retrieve the value. Some Map implementations are extremely fast for retrieval. For example HashMap and ConcurrentSkipListMap.
Map< EmpId , Employee > mapOfEmpIdToEmployees = new HashMap<>() ;
…
mapOfEmpIdToEmployees.put( idOfAlice , employeeAlice ) ;   // Store
…
Employee alice = mapOfEmpIdToEmployees.get( idOfAlice ) ;  // Retrieve


Thanks for all your time and explanation. It's very helpful form me!!!
